# How do I let the DOM know about new elements created on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am making an AJAX call and I am building some HTML on the backend side. I am returning them as a JSON and then using jQuery I render them, something like:

```
$(data.message).each(function (index, value) {
    $('#states_table tbody').append('<td>' + value.edit_link + '</td>');
});
```

`value.edit_link` contains the following HTML:

```
<a id="edit_0" 
   title="Edit" 
   onclick="javascript:return false;" 
   class="edit"
>Edit</a>
```

Then I will end up with something like this:

[image]

And as you can see the link doesn't have the hand cursor. My guess is that the DOM doesn't know about them when the page is rendered for first time so no CSS properties or default properties will be applied which makes me ask:

In order to have the links with the `cursor: hand`, how do I let the DOM know about this new elements?

Comment: Those are provinces!

Comment: @Datsik don't care about the title, is something I wrote there, I know those are provinces but thanks for the heads up

Comment: Sorry couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Add to your link html `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"` so:

```
<a href="#"
   id="edit_0" 
   title="Edit" 
   onclick="javascript:return false;" 
   class="edit"
>Edit</a>
```

For a full comprehension of `<a>` html tag read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

If you don't know if is better `href="#"` or `href="javascript:void(0)"` (nobody knows) read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-to-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0).

**Solution 2**

Don't use an `<a>` but a `<button>` following [the sentiment](https://twitter.com/chriscoyier/status/411195861918429184):

> if `<a>` button doesn’t have a meaningful href, it’s a `<button>`

(for someone a `<button>` outside a `<form>` feels wrong. You decide.)

so:

```
<button id="edit_0" 
   onclick="javascript:return false;" 
   class="edit"
>Edit</button>
```

Button reference [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Sometimes it's those simple ones that are easiest to overlook!

Comment: They shouldn't be links but buttons.